# MongoDB - Update all documents in a collection, adding a new field using value from another field that is already present in the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongo-shell, mongodb-compass

I have a MongoDB collection consisting of such documents:

```
{
 title: "Foo",
 subtitle: "Bar"
}
```

Due to development necessities, I want to bulk upload all the documents, adding a `title_lower` key to each of these documents, which is the existing document title saved as a lower-case string:

```
{
 title: "Foo",
 subtitle: "Bar",
 title_lower: "foo"
}
```

I'm using a Node.js server and Mongoose to communicate with the database, but I would like to avoid writing a one-time method on the server to do this operation.

I have downloaded MongoCompass hoping the MongoSH (shell) could help me achieve this, but I'm having trouble reusing the existing document values, to $set a new `title_lower` one.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run query in mongodb compass shell (_MONGOSH)

```
db.<CollectionName>.updateMany({ }, [{$set: {"title_lower": { $toLower: "$title" }}}], {upsert: false})
```

I tried and it works fine on my end, but I would suggest to try it on a test collection before updating your real collection.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. It worked as wanted.

Comment: I was looking for something similar and ended up in this answer, which looks good, just to add that, according to docs, `upsert` defaults to `false`, so maybe not needed in this particular example https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

Comment: When you are writing a query that will affect big dataset, it's always better to be explicit about the options you are passing even the default ones. If this query is to be used by your teammate who doesn't have a too much experience, he might accidently put `upsert: true` if he looks at the documentation. Always future proof your queries that have large effect